# d3.js map dont show data

Tags: json, dictionary, d3.js

js map dont show any kind off data.

What's wrong with my implementation

```
d3.json("app/asserts/oowvShapes.json", function (error, oowv) {
    if (error) return console.error(error);
    console.log(oowv);
    var width = 600,
        height = 900;

    var svg = d3.select("radarMap").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    svg.append("path")
        .datum({ type: "FeatureCollection", features: "features" })
        .attr("d", d3.geo.path());
```

I bind d3.min.js in index.html

My Json File :

```
"features": [
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "Gem_kurz": "Wangerooge",
    "Shape_Leng": 20564.5414369,
    "Shape_Area": 8294404
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [ 3425411.000000002, 5960849.999999998 ],
        [ 3425310, 5960849.999999998 ],
        [ 3425239.999999999, 5960920 ],
        [ 3425214.000000001, 5961024.000000002 ],
        [ 3425207.000000001, 5961189 ],
        [ 3425128.999999999, 5961361.000000002 ],
        [ 3425008.000000001, 5961501.000000002 ],
        [ 3424851.000000002, 5961666 ],
        [ 3424725, 5961826.000000004 ],
        [ 3424634, 5961973.000000002 ],
        [ 3424545.999999999, 5962033.000000002 ],
        [ 3424424, 5962108.000000004 ],
        [ 3424380, 5962135.000000002 ],
        [ 3424277.000000001, 5962195.000000002 ],
        [ 3424161.000000001, 5962334.999999998 ],
        [ 3424135, 5962455.000000004 ],
        [ 3424154.000000001, 5962530 ],
        [ 3424274.000000001, 5962658.000000002 ],
        [ 3424392.000000001, 5962746.000000002 ],
        [ 3424503, 5962823.000000002 ],
        [ 3424619.999999999, 5962947 ],
        [ 3424737.999999999, 5963016 ],
        [ 3425025, 5963122 ],
        [ 3425247, 5963153.000000002 ],
        [ 3425531.000000001, 5963173 ],
        [ 3425983, 5963161.000000002 ],
        [ 3426472.000000001, 5963202 ],
        [ 3426930.999999999, 5963178 ],
        [ 3427282.000000001, 5963173 ],
        [ 3427689.000000001, 5963101.000000002 ],
        [ 3428022.000000001, 5963077 ],
        [ 3428495, 5962979 ],
        [ 3429071, 5962825.000000004 ],
        [ 3429519.000000001, 5962737.000000004 ],
        [ 3429927, 5962681.000000002 ],
        [ 3430296.000000001, 5962592.000000002 ],
        [ 3430599.000000001, 5962494 ],
        [ 3430777.000000001, 5962415 ],
        [ 3430837.000000001, 5962355 ],
        [ 3430821.000000001, 5962295 ],
        [ 3430756.000000001, 5962243 ],
        [ 3430712, 5962172.000000002 ],
        [ 3430768.000000001, 5962077 ],
        [ 3430878, 5961999 ],
        [ 3431340.000000002, 5961839.999999998 ],
        [ 3431618, 5961740 ],
        [ 3431983.000000002, 5961588.000000002 ],
        [ 3432183, 5961452 ],
        [ 3432216.999999999, 5961363.000000004 ],
        [ 3432168.000000001, 5961298.000000004 ],
        [ 3432204, 5961218.000000002 ],
        [ 3432147.000000001, 5961159.000000002 ],
        [ 3432118, 5961111.000000002 ],
        [ 3432153, 5961054 ],
        [ 3432208, 5961008 ],
        [ 3432242.000000001, 5960936.000000002 ],
        [ 3432198.000000001, 5960904.000000002 ],
        [ 3432065, 5960884 ],
        [ 3431887, 5960989 ],
        [ 3431760.000000001, 5961111.000000002 ],
        [ 3431633.000000001, 5961245 ],
        [ 3431505, 5961329.000000002 ],
        [ 3430693, 5961728.999999998 ],
        [ 3430578.000000001, 5961733.000000004 ],
        [ 3430464, 5961624 ],
        [ 3430292.000000002, 5961506.000000002 ],
        [ 3430068, 5961513 ],
        [ 3429899.000000002, 5961531 ],
        [ 3429746.000000002, 5961529.000000002 ],
        [ 3429650, 5961526 ],
        [ 3429505.000000001, 5961547.000000002 ],
        [ 3429369.000000002, 5961585.000000004 ],
        [ 3429322.000000001, 5961533.000000002 ],
        [ 3429213.000000001, 5961568 ],
        [ 3429107.000000001, 5961568 ],
        [ 3428878.000000001, 5961562.000000004 ],
        [ 3428564.000000002, 5961591 ],
        [ 3428232, 5961666 ],
        [ 3427884.000000002, 5961793.000000004 ],
        [ 3427552.000000001, 5961954.000000002 ],
        [ 3427409.000000001, 5962033.000000002 ],
        [ 3427212.000000001, 5962101 ],
        [ 3426927, 5962180.000000002 ],
        [ 3426464, 5962316.000000004 ],
        [ 3426279, 5962434 ],
        [ 3426108, 5962522 ],
        [ 3425950.000000002, 5962510.000000002 ],
        [ 3425844, 5962430.000000002 ],
        [ 3425741.999999999, 5962273.000000002 ],
        [ 3425678, 5962124 ],
        [ 3425573.000000002, 5961946.000000004 ],
        [ 3425557, 5961794 ],
        [ 3425520, 5961696.000000004 ],
        [ 3425495, 5961469.999999998 ],
        [ 3425487.000000001, 5961306.000000002 ],
        [ 3425542.999999999, 5961226 ],
        [ 3425608, 5961179 ],
        [ 3425623.000000001, 5961125.000000002 ],
        [ 3425593.000000001, 5961045 ],
        [ 3425499.000000002, 5960912 ],
        [ 3425411.000000002, 5960849.999999998 ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}, .....
```

Full json : https://www.dropbox.com/s/wa3hahk9u8rh9cv/oowvShapes.json?dl=0

Can anyone help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are two things.**

**first** the structure of your call i would suggest you to do it like so:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
               .data(oowv.features)
               .enter()
               .append("path")
               .attr("d", path);
```

**second:**
Your problem seems to be with your data.
If I'm not mistaken, those coordinates use the Ordnance Survey National Grid reference system. By default, geoJSON expects the coordinates to be WGS84(longitude, latitude). You can try converting the shape files again and making sure that the output reference system is WGS84. You can do this in QGIS by saving the file as geoJSON and selecting WGS84 as the output coordinate reference system.

The resulting geoJSON should work fine. So to answer your question, update the code . in your file the format is correct. It's the coordinates that aren't right.